# Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 0 at GreetingClient.main(GreetingClient.java:12)

Tags: java, console-application

I have a simple **console application** that won't compile. I don't       understand the error. My code is:

```
 import java.net.*;
 import java.io.*;

 public class GreetingClient 
 {
     public static void main(String [] args)
     {
         String serverName = args[0];
         int port = Integer.parseInt(args[1]);
```

The error is :

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 0
at GreetingClient.main(GreetingClient.java:12)
```

1. What causes this error?
2. How do I fix it?

Comment: I have new programmer in java.My code is about Network programming.

Comment: Did you send any input parameters? If not, how can servername and port exsist if you didn't tell what their values are?

Comment: ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException is a runtime exception. Your code compiles. It gives an error at runtime (which is after compilation).

Comment: `int port = Integer.parseInt(args[1]);` You dont have anything set for `args[1]`... That's what I'm assuming anyways... the error is at line 12 and you've only shown us 9 lines...

Answer (score 0):

You're not sending any parameter when executing the application. Execute it like this:

```
java GreetingClient yourServerName 9090
                    ^arguments start here
                    they will be sent as Strings in String[] args
                    args[0] = yourServerName
                    args[1] = 9090
```

If you're using an IDE, then provide which one you use to add the info on how to add parameters when executing a class there.

Comment: Thanks for it.But how add Parameters?

Comment: How do you execute your app?

Comment: I want to execute socket programming on one computer.Is it possible?

Comment: @mehdighoncheh yes it is, but this questions belongs to a single problem. I won't try to solve all your questions here, only the question in your post.